# Filtering a dataframe by two columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need some tips about a pandas issue.

I have the following DataFrame, df1, which contains the names in the dates that I need to keep in the output dataframe:

```
name      date          column_1     column_11     
Anne      2018-01-01    some info1    some info11
John      2018-01-01    some info1    some info11
Mark      2018-02-01    some info1    some info11
Ethan     2018-03-01    some info1    some info11
Anne      2018-04-01    some info1    some info11
Ethan     2018-04-01    some info1    some info11
```

I have this other DataFrame, df2, that contains all the names and dates in my data sample:

```
name     date           column_2    column_22
Bob      2018-01-01     some info2   some info22
Bob      2018-01-01     some info2   some info22
Anne     2018-01-01     some info2   some info22
John     2018-01-01     some info2   some info22
Mark     2018-02-01     some info2   some info22
Mark     2018-02-01     some info2   some info22
Ethan    2018-03-01     some info2   some info22
Anne     2018-04-01     some info2   some info22
Anne     2018-04-01     some info2   some info22
Ethan    2018-04-01     some info2   some info22
Carl     2018-01-01     some info2   some info22
Joe      2018-01-01     some info2   some info22
```

And, as an output, I need a DataFrame like df1, but with all the columns in  df2.

Note that df1 and df2 have other columns in addition to the ones I show, thus they have different information. The thing is, I want the columns in df2, but only with the names in the dates shown in df1.

Sample output would be:

```
name      date          column_2     column_22     
Anne      2018-01-01    some info2    some info22
John      2018-01-01    some info2    some info22
Mark      2018-02-01    some info2    some info22
Mark      2018-02-01    some info2    some info22
Ethan     2018-03-01    some info2    some info22
Anne      2018-04-01    some info2    some info22
Anne      2018-04-01    some info2    some info22    
Ethan     2018-04-01    some info2    some info22
```

**NOTE:**

**doing:**

> df = df2.merge(df1)

**Didn't work**

**NOTE 2:**

df1 contains aggregated and filtered data from df2, that's why there are less rows in df1 than in df2. I just want to keep, in df2, those rows that contain the name and the date in df1.

None of the solutions work, so I thought maybe this explanation would help get the right anser.

Comment: Have you tried `df = df1.merge(df2, on=['name', 'date'] , how='left')`?

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide `d1.dtypes` and `d2.dtypes`. My suspicion is that your date column got stored differently in two dfs.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
df_out = (df1.reset_index()[["name", "date"]]
          .merge(df2.reset_index(), on=["name", "date"], how="inner"))
```

Comment: This isn't working, I get an empty dataframe as a result.

Comment: If you'd share a reproducible example I would be able to help you. What are the types of the columns?

Comment: name                    object
date                     datetime64[ns]
column_1             int64
column_11           int64

dtype: object -> for df1. For df2: column_22                      int64
date           datetime64[ns]
name         object
column_2   object
dtype: object

Comment: I just wanted to check if the keys I told you to merge on (`["name", "date"]`) are the same data type which, indeed, are. Then the code I am showing to you should not fail. Either the tables are not the same as the ones you pasted, or you don't have any coincidence between df1 and df2

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to do this in steps with intermediate `DataFrames`. This is less efficient but it will give you more insight into what is happening.

**Take only the name and date from `df1`**:

```
df_key = df1.loc[:, ["name", "date"]]
```

**Use an [inner join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) (referred to as a natural join in [this article](http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/join-merge-data-frames-pandas-python/)) of the key table and `df2`, which will produce only records where name and date match**:

```
df_out_1 = df_2.merge(
        df_key, 
        how="inner", 
        left_on=["name", "date"], 
        right_on=["name", "date"]
]
```

**Pick out the columns you want from the resulting join and you are done**:

```
df_out_2 = df_out_1.loc[:, ["name", "date", "column_2", "column_22"]]
```